# Using Microsoft Azure to run "a bunch of Python scripts on demand"

Tags: python, azure, queue

I'm trying to define an architecture where multiple Python scripts need to be run in parallel and on demand. Imagine the following setup:

script requestors (web API) -> Service Bus queue -> script execution -> result posted back to script requestor

To this end, the script requestor places a script request message on the queue, together with an API endpoint where the result should be posted back to. The script request message also contains the input for the script to be run.

The Service Bus queue decouples producers and consumers. A generic set of "workers" simply look for new messages on the queue, take the input message and call a Python script with said input. Then they post back the result to the API endpoint. But what strategies could I use to "run the Python scripts"?

Answer (score 0):

One possible strategy could be to use Webjobs.  Webjobs can execute Python scripts and run on a schedule.  Let's say that you run a Webjob every 5 minutes, the Python script can pool the queue, do some processing and post the results back to you API.

Answer (score 0):

Per my exprience, I think there are two strategies below you could use.

1. Developing a Python script for Azure HDInsight. Azure HDInsight as a platform based on Hadoop that has the power of parallel compute, you can try to refer to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-streaming-python/ to know it.
2. Develoging a Python script based on the parallel compute framework like [`dispy`](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/#) or [`jug`](http://luispedro.org/software/jug/) running Azure VMs.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.